# How to build a function that will show a needed list of "echos"?

Tags: bash, function, echo, counter

I want to make a function that will check a number between 1-5
and according to number it gets, it will output the amount of echo lines, as in following example:

```
if number 1-5 then show the list of outputs according to chosen number 
so

if 2 then act as following: 
echo "one" <------start here
echo "two" <------stop here
echo "three"

the end output put will be:

one 
two

if 3 then act as following:
echo "one" <------start here
echo "two" 
echo "three" <------stop here

the end output will be:

one
two
three
```

I need it in one function.
I know it can be done the hard way, as following:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $num = 1 ]]; then
echo "one"
fi

if [[ $num = 2 ]]; then
echo "one"
echo "two"
fi
```

but it will be too long if I will have to do it 50 times. I am sure there is an alternative way for that.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend researching _loops_ in bash.

Comment: just `seq $num`?

Comment: Do you want your function to output the word "echo" as well? Otherwise `seq` prints numbers from 1 to n

Comment: BTW, note for the future that if a question is asked incorrectly _but then answered in a way that's correct for how it was initially asked_, editing it in such a way as to invalidate those correct answers is frowned on; asking a new/different question is generally the appropriate course of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop if you store the data you need in an associative array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
numbers=( [1]="one" [2]="two" [3]="three" [4]="four" [5]="five" )

max=${1:-5} # either use $1 or default to 5 if empty

for ((i=1; i<=max; i++)); do
  echo "${numbers[$i]}"
done
```

If this script is named `f`, behavior is as follows:

```
$ f 2
one
two
```

```
$ f 5
one
two
three
four
five
```

---

If your real use case involves running completely arbitrary commands, then your code might look more like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
steps=( [1]=step_one [2]=step_two [3]=step_three [4]=step_four [5]=step_five )
max=${1:-5}

step_one()   { echo "one"; }
step_two()   { echo "two"; }
step_three() { echo "three"; }
step_four()  { echo "four"; }
step_five()  { echo "five"; }

for ((i=1; i<=max; i++)); do
  "${steps[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks man, I will try to build it and will see how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Bash has a built in called `seq` - from `man seq` -

> NAME
> seq - print a sequence of numbers

So, if you just want to print the numbers -

```bash
seq 5
```

produces -

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

If you want the word "echo" attached - you can format the output with `-f`

```bash
seq -f "echo %2.0f" 5
```

This produces -

```
echo  1
echo  2
echo  3
echo  4
echo  5
```

Comment: Thanks for help man!!!  

I have a list of echoes that I need to be shown regarding to the number it gets from string

it can be 1-5, the number declares how many lines to show in output without the echo word, only the "1"

echo "one"
echo "two"
echo "three"

so if the number is 2, the output will show only:

one
two

Comment: `seq` is **not** built into bash. It's provided by some operating systems as an external tool, but not every bash installation has it.

Comment: @Max, your comment above differs from the question. The question shows printing `1`, `2`, `3`; not `one`, `two`, `three`.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, sorry for that, I just fixed my question to be more clearly to what result I need. :)

Comment: @Max, ...if that's what you need, why did you accept an answer that doesn't do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly more than you need, but it shows you how to count up to a specified number and use that counter to do something "useful".

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the function:
function printNumbersTo {
  local -i number=${1}                 # -i forces the variable into an integer.
  if [ "${number}" != "${1}" ]; then   # Make sure the input parameter was an integer.
    echo "'${1}' is not an integer."
    return 1
  fi

  local -i counter=0
  while [ ${counter} < ${number} ]; do
    ((counter++))
    echo "Number is '${counter}'."
  done
}

# Now call the function:
printNumbersTo 5
```

Comment: Note that `function funcname() {` merges the POSIX-standardized syntax `funcname() {` and the 1980s-ksh syntax `function funcname {` in a way that's incompatible with _both_ POSIX sh and legacy ksh. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. I guess my 1980s training is shining through. Changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) and feed the lines one by one to a `for` loop:

```bash
for e in $(seq $1); do read -r line && echo "$line"; done <<EOF
one
two
three
four
five
EOF
```

Or just use `head`:

```bash
head -n $1 <<EOF
one
two
three
four
five
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Help! now it's working as expected :)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter num:"

read num

steps=( [1]=step_one [2]=step_two [3]=step_three [4]=step_four [5]=step_five [6]=step_six [7]=step_seven [8]=step_eight [9]=step_nine [10]=step_ten )

step_one()   { echo "one"; }
step_two()   { echo "two"; }
step_three() { echo "three"; }
step_four()  { echo "four"; }
step_five()  { echo "five"; }
step_six()   { echo "six"; }
step_seven()   { echo "seven"; }
step_eight() { echo "eight"; }
step_nine()  { echo "nine"; }
step_ten()  { echo "ten"; }

for ((i=1; i<=max; i++)); do
          "${steps[$i]}"
done
```